# Is the age of marriage for shafi fiqh 15 years?

Tags: nikah, shafii

According to [Tafsir Al-Jalalayn](http://quranx.com/Tafsirs/4.6) of verse 4.6:

> Try test well the orphans before reaching maturity with regard the
>   duties of religion and before they can legally manage their own
>   affairs until they reach the age of marrying that is until they have
>   become eligible for it through puberty or legal age which according to
>   al-Shāfi‘ī is the completion of fifteen years; then if you perceive in
>   them maturity that is right judgement in matters of religion and their
>   property deliver their property to them; consume it not O guardians
>   wastefully without due merit and in haste that is hastening to expend
>   it fearing lest they should grow up and become mature at which time
>   you will be obliged to hand it over to them.
>
> If any man who is a guardian is rich let him be abstinent that is let
>   him abstain from the orphan’s property and refrain from consuming it;
>   if he is poor let him consume of it honourably that is in line with
>   the wage for his work. And when you deliver to them the orphans their
>   property take witnesses over them that they have received it and that
>   you are absolved of the obligation so that if any dispute occurs you
>   are able to refer to a clear proof this is a command intended for
>   guidance. God suffices as a reckoner as a guardian of His creatures’
>   deeds and as a reckoner of these deeds the bā’ in bi’Llāhi is extra.

I Googled to find if it is the official position of Shafi fiqh but didn't find any authoritative reference. Is it the official opinion of Shafi madhab?

Comment: My answer [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/35669/17702) has relevant references.

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**: The tafsir is consistent with the technical age of *puberty*, but Shafi'i sources describe prepubescent marriage of a girl as legal when agreed to by her father of paternal grandfather.

---

The place to look is *The Reliance of the Traveller*, The Classic Manual of Islamic Sacred Law 'Umdat al-Salik, by Ahmad ibn Naqib al-Misri (translated by [Nuh Ha Mim Keller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuh_Ha_Mim_Keller)).  One [Shafi'i fatwa](http://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33312) says: *It stands, without equal or competitor, as the primary Sunni manual of Islam in English.*

The aforementioned tafsir says:

> ... become eligible for it through puberty or legal age which according to al-Shāfi‘ī is the completion of fifteen years

This is consistent with *The Reliance*'s definition of puberty:

> k13.8 *Puberty* applies to a person after the first wet dream, or upon becoming fifteen (O: lunar) years old, or when a girl has her first menstrual period or pregnancy.

Here, "O:" indicates an "excerpt from the commentary of Sheikh 'Umar Barakat".

However, I didn't find this definition of "puberty" as a precondition for marriage.  In fact, *The Reliance* discusses the legalities of prepubescent marriage:

> m3.9 Whenever a free woman asks to marry a suitor who is a suitable match (def: m4) (O: by telling her guardian, "Marry me to him"), the guardian must marry her to him (O: whether she is a virgin or nonvirgin, and whether prepubescent or not).
>
> m3.13 ... Whenever the bride is a virgin, the father or father's father may marry her to someone without her permission, though it is recommended to ask her permission if she has reached puberty. A virgin's silence is considered as permission.
>
> m8.2 A guardian may not marry his prepubescent daughter to someone for less than the amount typically received as marriage payment by similar brides, nor marry his prepubescent son to a female who is given more than the amount typically received. If he does either of these, the amount stipulated is void and the amount typically received is paid instead (O: in both these cases, as a necessary condition for the validity of the marriage contract).

(The conditions of m4 are not relevant to the question.)

This is likewise reflected in Islam Q&A fatawa [22442](https://islamqa.info/en/22442) and [146882](https://islamqa.info/en/146882) which reference [al-Shaafa’i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shafi%E2%80%98i).

Mahdi Zahraa (1996), *The Legal Capacity of Women in Islamic Law*, 11 Arab Law Quarterly ([JStor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3381878?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) likewise describes the situation (p.259) as:

> Compulsory guardianship (*wilayat al-ijbar*) is designed to enable young males and females to conclude a marriage contract at an earlier age than maturity. The guardian, who is exclusively supposed to be the natural father or grandfather, can conclude a marriage contract on behalf of his son or daughter if he/she is under the age of maturity, and the concluded marriage contract is sound and valid.